# How can I return ResultSet before closing the connection in Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset

I want to write only 1 execute method and re-use it whenever I need without rewrite the whole thing. Below is my method to return a ResultSet.

```
public ResultSet executeSelect() {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement prepared = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        con = C_DB.getConnection();
        prepared = con.prepareStatement(this.getQuery());

        if(!this.midQuery.equals("")) {
            int i = 1;
            for (String val: this.values) {
                prepared.setString(i, val);
                i++;
            }
        }

        rs =  prepared.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (prepared != null) {
                prepared.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return rs;
}
```

The problem is after executeSelect() executed, Connection, PreparedStatement and  ResultSet are closed before returning data so I got this error `java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`

The reason I want to return the ResultSet is I can re-use the executeData method for any object data. For example:

```
C_Query q = new C_Query(dataSearch,"SELECT * FROM people ", " ORDER BY id DESC");
ResultSet rs = q.executeSelect()

ObservableList<C_Person> peopleData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
while(rs.next()){
    C_Person person = new C_Person();
    person.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
    person.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
    peopleData.add(person);
}
```

**AND**

```
C_Query q = new C_Query(dataSearch,"SELECT * FROM cars", " ORDER BY id DESC");
ResultSet rs = q.executeSelect()

ObservableList<C_Car> CarData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
while(rs.next()){
    C_Car car = new C_Car();
    car.type(rs.getString("type"));
    car.brand(rs.getString("brand"));
    CarData.add(car);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look at spring-Jdbc for an example of a good way to make a thin wrapper around jdbc. It uses callbacks to populate objects from  Resultsets. ORMs like hibernate are powerful but have a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I want to return the ResultSet is I can re-use the
>   executeData method for any object data

**You can't `close` the `ResultSet` & `Connection` objects before reading the results from the database**, rather you need to `close` the `ResultSet` & `Connection` objects in the calling methods i.e., whenever you are reading the results are completed.

I think your objective is **to avoid the boilerplate code and populate the objects** (like your `C_Person` or `C_Car`, etc..) from the database, then  I strongly suggest, you need to go for the ORM (which maps a Java object to a relational table) frameworks like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/).

Answer (score 1):

There is 'CachedRowSet', exactly for that:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html

Answer (score 0):

You have *finally* block here. It is executed whenever there was an exception or not, so it closes the connection in any case before you return the result set from the method.

Comment: Shouldn't the resultset be stored outside of the try/catch anyway?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class and set to it the following methods, then you can call them from where you want

```
public static void openConnection(String db, String user, String password){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+db, user, password);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection conn, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs ){
    if (rs != null) {
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) { /* Ignored */}
}
if (ps != null) {
    try {
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) { /* Ignored */}
}
if (conn != null) {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) { /* Ignored */}
}

}
```